# Pulling outlet from existing 220 switch

Tags: switch, receptacle

trying to install an outlet in the HVAC closet next to an existing switch. The switch has 2 black wires, 2 red wires and a ground wire connected to it. There is also a lose white wire in the back, which i would assume is neutral, but when measuring voltage between Neutral and Ground there is none. Any ideas if and how i could power an outlet from this?

Comment: How fat are the wires (i.e. what gauge are they)? What does this switch control, for that matter?

Comment: It's possible that if the white is from the source cable that since it wasn't needed then it isn't terminated in the source panel.

Comment: Switch controls AC, and it would seem as though it also controls the water heater. The cables are 10awg. I uploaded pics of the box to my google drive in case that helps https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zawFcIqhvm1NPZPVzuUmOdQs1vC4Gdcx

Comment: btw, outlet im wanting to install can be 110 or 220, its only going to be used to power dyson vacuum charger which has transformer which takes either input

Comment: Need to see more of the inside of the box. You've got a double pole single throw switch in there that doesn't look like it controls two devices. With all that FMT in there you'd expect more wires and wire nuts.

Comment: That,s not a *transformer* then; it's a *switching power supply*; it matters here.  What kind of plug does it have? Is it a wall-wart, a lump with prongs coming out of it? (They're 120V oriented, right?)

Comment: *"There is also a lose white wire in the back, which i would assume is neutral, but when measuring voltage between Neutral and Ground there is none"* - That's the way it is **supposed** to be.

Comment: yes, its a switching power supply 120v oriented

Comment: Is it wired from the main panel with conduit, or does that conduit turn into a cable at some point?

Comment: I would be verifying the AC load because it is in a closet ,  if just an air handler the load will be tiny and with a universal switching supply 120-240v rated supply you could easily use that. Most AC systems that require a closet will have an air handler and the outside unit or compressor on a larger circuit so we need to know more about the system.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Can't put a receptacle here

Receptacles are not allowed on a circuit if more than half its capacity is provisioned to hardwired loads.  A built-in air conditioner circuit will be 22A or so.

### Can't put 15/20A receptacles on a 30A circuit

The circuit is breakered for 30A.  That means you can't have a 15A or 20A recep on it, in any case.

### The wall-wart doesn't lend itself to hardwiring... Unless it does

All the Dyson power supplies I turned up in a search were "hang off a socket" type wall-warts, and had a built-in plug matched to local power.  Presumably yours is NEMA 1-15 or 5-15.  If instead of a plug there were a pair of wires, we could make a case for "hard-wiring" the load, dodging the "no receptacles" and "no 15/20A receptacles" rules.  However, I don't see a way to attach wires to that which I could defend to the inspector with a straight face.

There's also a question of whether the power supply is a factor in the battery charging.  Batteries - especially the popular lithium batteries - *absolutely require* circuitry to prevent overcharging.   If the vacuum simply wants a generic DC voltage such as 12 volts, *and has that charge-controller circuitry onboard*, then we can substitute any generic DC power supply of the coarsely correct voltage, and that can include supplies that lend themselves to hard-wiring.  However, if the "keep the lithium battery from exploding" charge control circuitry is in the Dyson wall-wart, then we ned a Dyson branded supply involved *somehow*.

See if Dyson makes a car charger (cigarette lighter) for it.  If they do, then any 12 volt DC power supply will do that supports hardwiring. It can be brought out to a cigarette lighter socket if it doesn't have one built-in. Then, use the Dyson car charger.

### Don't trust that neutral

It's probably not even connected in the panel. By the way, the way you test it is measuring 120V between each hot and neutral.  Regardless, I would just wire up the load 240V, as that dodges *multi-wire branch circuit* complications.  Do not under any circumstance put a NEMA 5 socket on 240V.

Comment: We don’t know enough about the system to state a value for the AC system. If there is a inside air handler and outside compressor circuit it is common for them to be on different circuits.